# match something ended with a specific char BUT not those which have something in front of the ending char

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following string:

> aaa'dd?'d'xxx'

The delimiter is

> '

but if it has

> ?

in front of it, it should not be consider delimiter but just a literal (the ? is a escape character for delimiter).
The result I want to display is:

> aaa
>
> dd'd
>
> xxx

In this moment I am using [^']+ which does not take into consideration the escaping character(?).

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Post the query you're currently using.

Comment: Should your output have `dd?'d` rather than `dd?d`?

Comment: @AlexPoole: in fact, I want to have dd'd instead of dd?d. I modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to this without replacing the `?'` pattern with a fixed dummy character - whether that's a `'#'` or anything else you are sure will never actually appear - then you can use a regular expression pattern like this:

```
-- bind variable for sample value
var str varchar2(20);
exec :str := q'[aaa'dd?'d'xxx']';

select regexp_substr(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as result
from dual
connect by level < regexp_count(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)');

RESULT              
--------------------
aaa
dd?'d
xxx
```

and you can then just apply a simple replace afterwards:

```
select replace(
  regexp_substr(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)', 1, level, null, 1),
   '?''',
   '''') as result
from dual
connect by level < regexp_count(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)');

RESULT              
--------------------
aaa
dd'd
xxx
```

If you have two adjacent unescaped delimiters you get a null element back from that position (this didn't happen with an earlier version of the regex pattern):

```
exec :str := q'[aaa''dd?'d'xxx']';
-- just to make them more visible...
set null (null)

select replace(
  regexp_substr(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)', 1, level, null, 1),
   '?''',
   '''') as result
from dual
connect by level < regexp_count(:str, '((.*?[^?])*?)(''|$)');

RESULT              
--------------------
aaa
(null)
dd'd
xxx
```

Comment: can you tell em what modification should I made on the regex, as my select returns also NULLs? For eample, it might be possible to have string like this: **aaa''dd?'d'xxx'**, and the expected result to be :
aaa<br/>
null<br/>
dd'd<br/>
xxx

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to replace *offending* string with something else; for example, I used `#`. For the final result, replace it with a single quote, `'`.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select q'[aaa'dd?'d'xxx']' from dual),
  3  inter as
  4    (select replace(col, '?''', '#') icol
  5     from test
  6    )
  7  select replace(regexp_substr(icol, '[^'']+', 1, level), '#', '''') result
  8  from inter
  9  connect by level <= regexp_count(icol, '''');

RESULT
-------------
aaa
dd'd
xxx
```

Comment: This helps but I had I typo in my question. As the result, I wanted to say I need dd'd instead of dd?d

Comment: @mikcutu - so change the final `replace()` to use `''''` instead of `'?'`.

Comment: OK then; Alex told you what to do, I modified REPLACE so that it reflects what you've said.

Comment: is there any possibility to do that without replacing ?' with #? I am asking that, as for general purpose, it might happen to really have the # simbol into the text and don't want to be replace with ?' at line 7. Is it possible?

Comment: I wouldn't know; I'm not that good in regular expressions. If some of the experts sees your question, you might get the answer.